# Is there a way to keep my fluid design from breaking when using percentages and relative positioning?

Tags: html, css

I make use of percentages by specifying the width of elements I want to stretch and percentages when specifying "left" "left:40%;" for example and a relative position. This allows elements to move with the page when it's resized and stretch but at certain resolutions sizes the elements don't entirely stay in place. Am I stuck using media queries for this issue or is there another way? I'm still using media queries but I also don't want my design breaking so early before reaching breakpoints, I want it to be as flexible/elastic as possible before having to have media queries kick in.

Comment: percentage and relative wont break....

Comment: They are for me, when my browser is at full screen, the elements don't maintain their position relative to other elements.

Comment: https://www.ocutag.com/  my experience

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of worrying about those wacky sizes where your page looks funky, you should think about the most common screen sizes that are actually used.

I know exactly what you mean about those breakpoints. That's why I use screenfly to test my site on the most common screen sizes and work from there.

And if your site elements aren't maintaining your desired positions, then you are probably calculating the percentages wrongly. Here is a great article that helped me with fluid layouts and how to set up the percentages and what-not: http://www.creativebloq.com/css3/create-fluid-layouts-html5-and-css3-9122768

Answer (score 0):

Use `float: left` with a percentage width instead, and that should accomplish what you need. If you're using `left: 40%` for an offset (gap or spacing), try using `margin-left`.